# list.append(variable) doesn't append but replaces the list

Tags: python, list, function, append

I have created a function which creates an empty list, and assigns a value from another list to a variable. Then the code is supposed to append the variable's value to the list each time the function is called. But the function doesn't append, but instead replaces the element inside the list. I can tell this because when I print the list, the previous element is missing. The code is below. I need this for a mock examination. Any ideas?

```
def track():
    global tracker
    global trackerresult
    trackerresult = []
    tracker = opposite1[decider]
    trackerresult.append(tracker)
    print(trackerresult)
```

Comment: Put `trackerresult = []` outside of the function and it should work. Maybe rethink whether or not you need global variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the append that is doing that, but your explicit replacement of the existing variable two lines earlier.

As CactusWoman points out, you don't need globals here at all. `tracker` is a purely local variable; and as for `trackerresult`, once you've got rid of the assignment you'll only be *mutating* it, so there is no need to declare it as global.

Comment: "tends to"? You really need to gain a better understanding of what your code is doing. Adding `global` randomly might fix one thing, but will probably cause other problems which are harder to find. In this case, it sounds like you need a class.

Comment: Makes sense. Didn't think of that. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Every single time out run the `track` function, it resets the value 
`trackerresult` to the empty list. If you didn't explicitly empty the list, instead doing `trackerresult=[]` once before the function definition, it would work.